# how to show datetime format as dd-MMM-yy when its type is DateTime

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

below is purchase class,which contain property as orderdate with type datetime

```
public class Purchase
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string OrderNo { get; set; }      
    public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }     
    public string Location { get; set; }
}
```

when i create object of purchase i want to assign date to it.and for output i want to show format as "dd-MMM-yy" eg. 27-May-14

i tried `purchase.OrderDate = Convert.ToDateTime("27-May-13");`
but it shows result as

```
5/27/2013 12:00:00 AM
```

Comment: Well where are you showing it? You've shown the property declaration, but nothing about where it's being displayed. (Searches for DateTime formatting MVC find a *lot* of hits, by the way... did you check those?)

Comment: `DateTime` doesn't have a format. `String` have. You can use `DateTime.ToString(string)` method for string representation of your `DateTime` value. Since you use MVC, you can use `DataFormatString` for your property.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this in your (View)Model:

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString="{0:dd-MMM-yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode=false)]
 public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }
```

and then use `Html.DisplayFor()` and `Html.EditorFor()` in Razor.

Answer (score 1):

`DateTime` has no format but if you want to format it  while displaying it to the user using some `custom format` you can use `ToString()` method as below

Try This:

```
var result = purchase.OrderDate.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy");
```

Answer (score 0):

The class has no format. A DateTime is a point in time defined as a number. The string representation is not done in the DateTime but when you convert it to a string. WHat you use as in put is totally irrelevant. It is not remembered.

So, if you want to show the datetime in a specific format, then format it in the view when you output it. Or set the default formatting in the thread (which will depend on ui culture mostly - unless you do not smart things - selected by the user in his browser settings).

Comment: i have used mvcgrid in view.and i want to show date in dd-MMM-yy format.but everytime im getting output as 5/27/2013 12:00:00 AM like this in grid view. how to change format of date in mvcgrid.

Comment: Ah, that is a otally different question, is it not? It is also a duplicate to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7326687/how-to-format-date-in-mvc-web-grid for example. Try using a little google - especially for trivial questions like this.

Comment: @Html.Grid(Model).Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Add(c => c.OrderNo).Titled("Order No").SetWidth(200).Sortable(true).Filterable(true);
        columns.Add(c => c.OrderDate).Titled("Order Date").SetWidth(200).Sortable(true).Filterable(true);
    }).WithPaging(5)               this is my code for mvcgrid. how to change date format using this